# Have popup show up below parent with horizontal alignment wpf

Tags: wpf, popup

How would I be able to have a popup which has a horizontal alignment to center, but still keep the placement to be below the parent item like this:

What I Have:

[image]

Code:

```
<ToggleButton Name="button" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <TextBlock>settings</TextBlock>
                    <!--<materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="PackageVariantClosed" Foreground="Black" Height="24" Width="24"/>-->
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}" StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="#222" Height="150" Width="250">
                <TextBlock>I'm the popup</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HorizontalOffset` property of the popup. If you know the width of the toggle button you can set a number in XAML:

```
 <Popup Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button}" 
       HorizontalOffset="-100"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=button}" StaysOpen="False">
```

If you want a more generic approach, in the code behind you can calculate the exact offset that is needed:

```
 popup.HorizontalOffset = -125 + button.ActualWidth / 2;
```